# searching "key" in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, search, key

Below you will see a snippet of a code where I created a dictionary in which words from a product review are stored. Now, I am writing a function that will return the number of occurrences of the word present in the dictionary. If it isn't present, it returns 0.

*(This function will be used later for another purpose. As one of the member pointed, I could use dict.get() to extract the key. however, when I tried that, I got an **attribute error:'SArray' object has no attribute 'get'**)*

Can anyone point out any obvious mistake I might have made?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Here is the code:

```
word_list=turicreate.text_analytics.count_words(products['review'])

def selected_w_count(key):
    if key in word_list:
        return word_list[key]
    else:
        return 0

selected_w_count('wise')

output ->> 0
```

[Snapshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bngl0.png)

Comment: You can use `dict.get` with default value, like `word_list.get('wise', 0)`, it will give `0` if key `wise` doesn't exist else it will return the value for the key.

Comment: Paste code as text not as an image.

Comment: I tried to do it this way but it gives an 'attribute error': 'SArray' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @NinadPethkar, then do `word_list[0].get('wise', 0)`

Comment: @NinadPethkar Then I don't think `SArray` is a dictionary; is it? (It seems like it's an array of dictionaries.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in `selected_w_count(key)` function, `if key in world_list:` should be `if key in word_list:`.

Based on your comment that the type of word_list is an array, you may want to use `word_list[0].get('wise', 0)` in place of the function call. This will get the dict from the array and get key 'wise' with a default value of 0.

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I corrected it and it still is giving the wrong output. I have now updated the original snapshot.

Comment: That only provides the words stored at word_list[0] If the word we are searching is in word_list[1] or word_list[n] then the method would still return "0

Comment: @NinadPethkar You can just iterate through it then...?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your code returns a turicreate.SArray object but not a standard dict object, so the get function don't work.

I search for the document and find it at:
https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/generated/turicreate.SArray.html

And maybe you can use the function turicreate.SArray.dict_trim_by_keys() to filter by the given keys and use turicreate.SArray.dict_values() to get the value, just like this:

```
def selected_w_count(key_word):
    word_list.dict_trim_by_keys([key_word], exclude=False).dict_values() if word_list.dict_trim_by_keys([key_word], exclude=False) else 0
```

You can also just provide a list of key words, just change it like this:

```
def selected_w_count(keywords_list):
    word_list.dict_trim_by_keys(keywords_list, exclude=False).dict_values() if word_list.dict_trim_by_keys(keywords_list, exclude=False) else 0
```

The documents of these functions are here:
https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/generated/turicreate.SArray.dict_trim_by_keys.html
https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/generated/turicreate.SArray.dict_values.html

Take care that the true result will also return A SArray of list type but not just a num.

Not sure whether it works, hope it can help you.